# AEM building package using Jenkins job

Tags: aem

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:99)
    at net.adamcin.granite.client.packman.AbstractPackageManagerClient.parseDetailedResponse(AbstractPackageManagerClient.java:383)
    at net.adamcin.granite.client.packman.async.AsyncPackageManagerClient.access$400(AsyncPackageManagerClient.java:60)
```

This error occured when Im running a jenkins job.
I do not find any solution in Java or Jenkins side.
Any pointer would help me..

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: please add more details, so that people can help you